# Creating PHP File From Another PHP File Inserting Variables

Tags: php

I am actually creating a PHP script, and it requires some database connection, it shall require the config.php file that contains Database details like this

```
$dbname = "coolsix"; 
$dbhost = "localhost";
```

Now, i dont want the users to create the file themselves, i want my install.php to create the file, but it is not inserting the details, i did this

```
if($_POST["submit"]) 
{//Retrieve form values
    $db_type=$_POST["db_type"];
    $db_name=$_POST["db_name"]; 
    $db_user=$_POST["db_user"];
    $db_host=$_POST["db_host"]; 
    $db_pass=$_POST["db_pass"];

    //Write 
    $my_file = '../config.php'; 
    $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file); 
    $data = '<?php  //PHP Downloader Configuration File global $config, $db; ?> <?php $dbhost = ".$db_host.";<br> $dbname = ".$db_name.";<br> $dbuser = ".$db_user.";<br> $dbpass = ".$db_pass.";<br> ?>'; 
    fwrite($handle, $data);
```

The config.php file is created, but it does not contain the values, it contains the variables, i expect it to replace `$dbname` with the value the user specify in the installation form. see the form http://loadedgeek.com/downloader/inis

Any idea?

Comment: Use [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents), [`HEREDOC`](http://php.net/HEREDOC) string, and [`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export) for correctness.

Comment: Variables in a single quoted string **are not parsed**

Comment: Thanks, fixed... I got my answer in the other question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have a few problems.  First, you need to use double-quotes so your variable substitution happens correctly.  Second, you want to escape the `$varname` with a backslash when you **don't** want the substitutions to happen.  Third, you have to account for the fact that people might have quotes inside their usernames, passwords, etc..

A simple way to build the string you want would be...

```
$db_type=addslashes($_POST["db_type"]);
$db_name=addslashes($_POST["db_name"]); 
$db_user=addslashes($_POST["db_user"]);
$db_host=addslashes($_POST["db_host"]); 
$db_pass=addslashes($_POST["db_pass"]);

$content = "<?php 
    \$dbhost = '$db_host';
    \$dbname = '$db_name';
    // etc...
";

file_put_contents($my_file, $content);
```

That general technique will work okay, most of the time.

A better way is to use an actual template library.  That way, you can make use of purpose-built filters that properly escape strings, neaten up the text, and put the template of the config file you are building in a separate file.